# Pounds and Ounces to Kilograms and grams. Driver Program Fail

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void convertWeight(double ounces, double grams, int pounds, int kilograms);
double output(double ounces, int pounds);

int main()
{
    double ounces, grams;
    int pounds, kilograms;
    char answer;

    do
    {
    cout << "Enter weight in pounds and ounces: " << endl;
    cin >> pounds >> ounces;
    cout << output(pounds, ounces) << endl;

    cout << "Do you want to test again (y/n)?: " << endl;
    cin >> answer;

    }while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y');

    return 0;
}

double output(double ounces, int pounds)
{
    double grams;
    int kilograms;

    convertWeight(ounces, grams, pounds, kilograms);

    cout << pounds << "pounds and " << ounces << "ounces = " << kilograms << "kilograms and " << grams << " grams." << endl;


    return 0;

}

void convertWeight(int pounds, double ounces, int &kilograms, double &grams)
{
    double temp = (pounds + ounces/16)/2.2046
    kilograms = temp;
    grams = (temp - kilograms) * 1000;
}
```

Alright I am trying to write a program that converts pounds and ounces to kilograms and grams. I must have pounds and kilograms as type int and ounces and grams as type double. I feel like there is something I have not done here. I am trying to use a driver program and call a function both by call-by-value and call-by reference parameters. I just compiled my program and got the longest list of errors I have ever seen and has errors I never seen before either. What is it that I have not added to the program that I should have?

here is my following error list:

```
warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
warning C4101: 'kilograms' : unreferenced local variable
warning C4101: 'grams' : unreferenced local variable
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'kilograms'
warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
```

Comment: Only an eagle can read what's written there.

Comment: Sorry I fixed with links so you can zoom in on them

Comment: That convert function is so wrong.

Comment: Thank you everyone who helped. I have fixed the rest of my problems and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append parameter types in function implementation: void convertWeight(ounces, grams, pounds, kilograms)

Answer (score 0):

I can't read all the error messages there, but I can tell you at least part of what's wrong with your programme :-)

```
void convertWeight(ounces, grams, pounds, kilograms)
{ 
    kilograms = (pounds + ounces/16)/2.2046;
    grams = kilograms * 1000;

    return(kilograms, grams);
}
```

Here, you've said that the function return type is `void`, i.e it doesn't return a value -- but then you've tried to return a value anyway! (In a way that isn't valid C++.) Furthermore, you've forgotten to specify the parameter types in the function definition, which is also not allowed in C++.

Rather than outputting a pair of values (which is possible, but in a different way to how you've tried to do it here), it would be easier to pass the `grams` and `kilograms` variables *by reference* -- this means that the function you call will change the variables you pass to them. You need to change your `convertWeight` function signature to

```
// Note the '&' on the reference variables
void convertWeight(int pounds, double ounces, int& kilograms, double& grams)
{
    kilograms = // whatever
    grams = // whatever
}
```

Now you can call `convertWeight()` like this:

```
int pounds = 3;
int ounces = 12;
int kilograms;
double grams;

convertWeight(pounds, ounces, kilograms, grams);
```

and your function will fill in the values of `kilograms` and `grams` for you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wong in the code. Let me concentrate on the `convertWeight` function.

First of all, write the **types** of the parameters in front of the parameter names, like you did with the `output` function.

Secondly, the function parameters are all "in" parameters, meaning they are used to pass in values which are copied to be used in the function. The function itself is allowed to modify them, but modifications are done locally and thrown away when returning from the function. You wanted to return two values which is not possible in C++ unless you wrap them into a single container type like `std::pair`. If you don't want to do this, you need to make two of your parameters "out" parameters, which can be done in C++ using **references**.

Finally, the conversion is wrong. Your assignment of the converted kilograms is stored in an int, which means that the decimal part is **truncated**. When multiplying by 1000 afterwards, you get a number divisible by 1000 which doesn't help much; even if it still was a double, your grams variable would not only have the grams but the full weight. I'm almost sure you only wanted to have the "remainder" of the kilograms expressed in grams. So use a temporary double variable to fix the first problem and subtract the kilograms before multiplying by 1000 to fix the second problem.

```
void convertWeight(double ounces, double &grams, int pounds, int &kilograms)
{
    double temp = (pounds + ounces/16)/2.2046;
    kilograms = temp;                  // will automatically truncate to full kilograms
    grams = (temp - kilograms) * 1000; // Will use the remainder
}
```

Also I don't like the **parameter order**, but that's a personal choice of preference. Typically you want to keep ins and outs separate. Also it makes more sense to put the "larger" unit before the "smaller" unit, resulting in this signature:

```
void convertWeight(int pounds, double ounces, int &kilograms, double &grams)
```